# .Net Maui Google Maps - Map.Default not available?

Tags: c#, google-maps, maui

I'm a little confused. I implemented google maps in .Net Maui, and am following the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/maps?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android). I can add pins to my map, but I don't have Map.Default, in order to pull the maps up to a default location on startup. My code:

```
    using Android.Telephony;
    using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Java.Lang;
    using System.Net;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    using Map = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps.Map;
    
    namespace CellularSignal1;
    
    public partial class Mapper : ContentPage
    {
        //filled in with code somewhere else
        private List<Tuple<double, double>> locations = new List<Tuple<double, double>>();

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            try
            {
                // map.Default doesn't exist
                // Map.Default doesn't exist
                for (int i = 0; i < locations.Count; i++)
                {
                    map.Pins.Add(new Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps.Pin
                    {
                        Label = $"BST#{i}",
                        Location = new Location(locations[i].Item1, locations[i].Item2)
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
                // No map application available to open
            }
        }
    }
```

Xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CellularSignal1"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps"
             x:Class="CellularSignal1.Mapper"
             x:DataType="local:Mapper"
             Title="Mapper">
    <maps:Map x:Name="map"/>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Map.Default opens the default map application on the device.  It does not work with a map control that is embedded in your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default implementation of the `IMap` interface is available through the [Map.Default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.applicationmodel.map.default?view=net-maui-7.0#microsoft-maui-applicationmodel-map-default) property. Both the `IMap` interface and `Map` class are contained in the `Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel` namespace.

There will be a conflict when you define `using Map = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps.Map;`. To fix the issue, just **eliminate** it. You can refer to the following example opening the installed map app at a specific or default GPS location when starting up the page.

**SAMPLE CODE:**

```
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {

        base.OnAppearing();


        var placemark = new Placemark
        {
            CountryName = "United States",
            AdminArea = "WA",
            Thoroughfare = "Microsoft Building 25",
            Locality = "Redmond"
        };
        var options = new MapLaunchOptions { Name = "Microsoft Building 25" };

        try
        {
            await Map.Default.OpenAsync(placemark, options);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // No map application available to open or placemark can not be located
        }
    }
```